# how to get the download url of an image on firebase in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Newly working with firebase with swift.
I'm trying to obtain the download url of an image that I already uploaded into firebase storage. I tried the following code:

```
    storageRef.downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    // Handle any errors
  } else {
    // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'
  }
}
```

I want to obtain the url as a string. What is a good practice?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `URL` is right there in your completion handler. What's the question/problem?

Comment: I wanted it as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to get Url String instead of Url, then you can use `absoluteString` of the Url to get the String Value.

```
storageRef.downloadURLWithCompletion { (URL, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    // Handle any errors
  } else {
    // Get the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'

    let UrlString = URL.absoluteString

   // you will get the String of Url
  }
}
```