# How To Get a URL for a Video Saved in Firebase Storage

Tags: swift, firebase-storage

For starters here is what I currently have:

```swift
    func uploadToCloud(fileURL: URL){
        
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        
        let data = Data()
        
        let storageRef = storage.reference()
        
        let localFile = fileURL
        
        let photoRef = storageRef.child("\(email)\(counter)")
                
        let uploadTask = photoRef.putFile(from: localFile, metadata: nil) { (metadata, err) in
            
            guard let metadata = metadata else {
                
                print(err?.localizedDescription)
                
                return
                
            }
```

To upload the video to storage ^

```swift
    func playVideo(url: URL) {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        
        let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
        vc.player = player
        
        self.present(vc, animated: true) { vc.player?.play() }
    }
```

This is what I have to play the video ^

Originally I tried also saving the link to Firestore, but all it saved was the files location, I believe on the phone which is not what I am trying to do. Is there a way to I can get a the url for the video saved in storage to run it as a url in the playVideo function?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the download url of an image on firebase in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289712/how-to-get-the-download-url-of-an-image-on-firebase-in-swift)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59872820/2781088

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get

```
// ....
    
    photoRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("DEBUG: Upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        return
                    }
                    guard let videoUrl = url?.absoluteString else {
                        print("DEBUG: Upload failed get URL")
                        return
                    }
                    completion(videoUrl)
                    
                }
```